# How to make my crawler parse data from start page

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, css-selectors, web-crawler

I've written some code in python to grab details from a torrent site. However, when I run my code I found the results as I expected. The only problem with this crawler is that it skips the content of first page [as the pagination urls start from 2] which I can't fix. Any help on this will be highly appreciable.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

page_link = "https://yts.ag/browse-movies"
b_link = "https://yts.ag"

def get_links(main_link):
    response = requests.get(main_link).text
    tree = html.fromstring(response)
    for item in tree.cssselect('ul.tsc_pagination a'):
        if "page" in item.attrib["href"]:
            movie_details(b_link + item.attrib["href"])

def movie_details(link):
    response = requests.get(link).text
    tree = html.fromstring(response)
    for titles in tree.cssselect("div.browse-movie-wrap"):
        title = titles.cssselect('div.browse-movie-bottom a.browse-movie-title')[0].text
        link = titles.cssselect('div.browse-movie-year')[0].text
        rating= titles.cssselect('figcaption.hidden-xs h4.rating')[0].text
        genre = titles.cssselect('figcaption.hidden-xs h4')[0].text
        genre1 = titles.cssselect('figcaption.hidden-xs h4')[1].text
        print(title, link, rating, genre, genre1)

get_links(page_link)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just call the `movie_details()` function on the main_link before the loop ?

```
def get_links(main_link):
    response = requests.get(main_link).text
    tree = html.fromstring(response)
    movie_details(main_link)
    for item in tree.cssselect('ul.tsc_pagination a'):
        if "page" in item.attrib["href"]:
            movie_details(b_link + item.attrib["href"])
```

Comment: Thanks PRMoureu, for your answer. Your solution always works. I noticed that many websites nowadays use this technique - not to include first page in the pagination urls. So, ain't there any better idea?

Comment: @SMth80  it seems to be the easiest  way when the start page displays the items instead of a "page 1", now you can also add a test to check the first page number collected by your query, and use this trick only if pages start from 2

Comment: I tested it in the first place and that is why i replied that your code always works. One more thing you should consider taking a look--when i scraped paginated urls i found that i got several duplicate urls. Any workaround from that? In your spare time you might think about it. Thanks a trillion for everything, PRMoureu.